# REF field omits nbsp in formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, field-codes

I'm trying to cross-refer a figure and apply some simple formatting to the cross-reference like this:

```
...as shown in Fig._{ REF _Ref30011011 \# "0,_c" \h }.
```

which should result in

```
...as shown in Fig._12,_c.
```

where the '_' symbol is NBSP.

Unfortunately, the result is

```
...as shown in Fig._12,c.
```

At least it's become non-breaking.

I've tried using `{ SYMBOL }` field like

```
...as shown in Fig._{ REF _Ref30011011 \# "0,{ SYMBOL 160 }c" \h }.
```

and `{ SET }` field like

```
{ SET NBSP "_"}
...as shown in Fig._{ REF _Ref30011011 \# "0,{ NBSP }c" \h }.
```

but nothing changed.

So the question is: is there a way to preserve NBSP that is used in the `\#` formatting switch?

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer, but the only solution I've been able to find so far is to use Word's Replace using wildcards after updating the fields:

FindWhat:="(Fig. *,)(?)"

ReplaceWith:="\1" & chr(160) & "\2"

Then, I created a class module for document events, declaring an object variable for the application `Public WithEvents oApp As Word.Application`, and creating the event procedure `Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)` in which I invoke the replacements.